# Optimized way to apply transformation on several columns of a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.2

In my spark jobs, I have to make transformations on multiple column for 2 use cases :

- **Casting columns**

In my personal use case, i use it on a Df of 150 columns

```
  def castColumns(inputDf: DataFrame, columnsDefs: Array[(String, DataType)]): DataFrame = {
    columnsDefs.foldLeft(inputDf) {
      (acc, col) => acc.withColumn(col._1, inputDf(col._1).cast(col._2))
    }
  }
```

- **Transformation**

In my personal use case, i use it to perform calculation n multiple column to create n new columns
(1 input col for  1 output col, n times)

```
    ListOfCol.foldLeft(dataFrame) {
      (tmpDf, m) => 
          tmpDf.withColumn(addSuffixToCol(m), UDF(m))
    }
```

As you saw, I use FoldLeft method and withColumn.
But i found out recently in the documentation that using **[withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#withColumn(colName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)** is not that good when used multiple times :

> this method introduces a projection internally. Therefore, calling it
> multiple times, for instance, via loops in order to add multiple
> columns can generate big plans which can cause performance issues and
> even StackOverflowException. To avoid this, use select with the
> multiple columns at once.

I also found that **foldleft** slowdown spark application because a full plan analysis is performed on every iteration. i think this is true beacause since i added foldleft in my code, my spark take more time to start a job than before.

**Is there good practice when applying transformations on multiple columns ?**

Spark version : 2.2
Language : Scala

Answer (score 0):

In the case of casting you can achieve what you're looking for with something like the following:

```
val df: DataFrame = ???
val cols = Array(("a", StringType), ("b", BooleanType), ("c", LongType)).map(c => col(c._1).cast(c._2))
val renamed = df.select(cols:_*)
```

It uses the method `select(cols: Column*): DataFrame` ([Spark 2.2 docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@select(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)) which takes a collection of `Column`s. The map on the variable `cols` creates the column expressions.

In the case of the transformations, it's not entirely clear to me what your doing, but a similar logic can be applied. I've made some best guesses regarding type signatures from your example:

```
def addSuffixToCol(c: Column): String = ???
def UDF(c: Column): Column = ???
val ListOfCol: List[Column] = ???
val dataFrame: DataFrame = ???
dataFrame.select(ListOfCol.map(c => UDF(c).as(addSuffixToCol(c))):_*)
```

As above, we apply the transformations on the columns in `ListOfCol` which are then used to select from `dataFrame`.

If you want to include other columns, add them to the select statement, eg:

```
dataFrame.select(col("foo"), col("bar"), ListOfCol.map(c => UDF(c).as(addSuffixToCol(c))):_*)
```

Comment: What if i dont want to cast all columns of my dataframe ? In your example, i columns that are not casted are not in the DF after the cast

Comment: @Marwan02: I've updated the answer to include that scenario. In short you are just dealing with a select statement, so you can select columns as you normally would.

Comment: There is no way to do it without specifying all columns like so : col("foo"), col("bar") ?
I have like 400 columns to add

Comment: I tried `dataFrame.select(dataFrame.columns.diff(ListOfCol).map(c => col(c)) +: ListOfCol.map(c => UDF(c).as(addSuffixToCol(c))):_*) `
But i get overloaded method value select with alternatives

Comment: You're almost there: you just need to give the compiler a little more help. Make sure that the two lists are joined in the `select` before you unpack them with as varargs. `dataFrame.select( (dataFrame.columns.diff(ListOfCol).map(col) :+ ListOfCol.map(c => UDF(c).as(addSuffixToCol(c)))):_*)`

Comment: I still have 
`overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  [U1](c1: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U1])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U1] <and>
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
`

Comment: The error is telling you that the compiler can't figure out the type of the input. Try and break things down to figure out why the error is occuring: `val myCols: List[Column] = dataFrame.columns.diff(ListOfCol).map(col) :+ ListOfCol.map(c => UDF(c).as(addSuffixToCol(c)); dataFrame.select(myCols:_*)`. If `myCols` has the right type, the next statement should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239069/discussion-between-marwan02-and-jarrod-baker).